# asp.net: How to "add role to user" in custom Login1_Authenticate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 3Layer ASP.NET project. I use a Login control with custom Login1_Authenticate. So I force Login control to use my own database and users. but the problem is adding roles to my users. control works fine with database, but I dont know how to add roles to my own users.

(note 1: I don't want to use "Web Site Administration Tool" to manage my users.)

(note 2: I configured aspnet_regsql.exe to my own database. but don't know hot to continue. )

my code:

```
            protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    e.Authenticated = false;
    try
    {
        BL_login G = new BL_login();
        G.username = Login1.UserName.Trim();
        G.password = Login1.Password.Trim();

        if (G.SelectAdmin().Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Login1.DestinationPageUrl = "Default.aspx";
            Roles.AddUserToRole(G.username, "admin");
            //Roles.AddUserToRole(G.username, "user");
        }
        else if (G.SelectUser().Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Login1.DestinationPageUrl = "Default.aspx";
            Roles.AddUserToRole(G.username, "user");
        }
        else { e.Authenticated = false; }
    }
    catch
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
}



    public class BL_login : DataAccess
{
    //---
    public string username;
    public string password;

    public DataTable SelectAdmin()
    {
        base.Link();
        string Query = "SELECT users.idUser AS [کد کاربری], zones.nam AS [منطقه], users.state AS [وضعیت], users.username AS [نام کاربری], users.password AS [رمز عبور], users.role AS [دسترسی] FROM users INNER JOIN zones ON users.idZone = zones.idZone WHERE users.username='{0}' AND users.password='{1}' AND users.state='{2}'AND users.role='{3}' ";
        Query = string.Format(Query, username, password, "1", "admin");
        DataTable Output_Q = base.SelectDataText(Query);
        base.UnLink();
        return Output_Q;
    }
    public DataTable SelectUser()
    {
        base.Link();
        string Query = "SELECT users.idUser AS [کد کاربری], zones.nam AS [منطقه], users.state AS [وضعیت], users.username AS [نام کاربری], users.password AS [رمز عبور], users.role AS [دسترسی] FROM users INNER JOIN zones ON users.idZone = zones.idZone WHERE users.username='{0}' AND users.password='{1}' AND users.state='{2}'AND users.role='{3}' ";
        Query = string.Format(Query, username, password, "1", "user");
        DataTable Output_Q = base.SelectDataText(Query);
        base.UnLink();
        return Output_Q;
    }
    //---
}
```

Comment: Has my answer resolved your question ?

Comment: @Seany84 your code works, but just for the first login. when the user log off, he cant log in again. you know, I'm just totally confused about how to work with roles of membership provider and users of my own database. I cant add roles of  membership provider  to users of my own database :(((

Comment: Since my question directly answered your question, it should be marked as the answer. You can't expect people to answer your question and then edit your question with a new problem. You should create a new question on StackOverflow. Link to you updating your question with my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45522998/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that you are using ASP.NET Membership:

```
if (G.SelectAdmin().Rows.Count != 0)
{
  e.Authenticated = true;
  Login1.DestinationPageUrl = "Default.aspx";
  Roles.AddUserToRole(G.username, "SomeRole");  
}
```